# Read SQL in pandas with parameter list or tuple

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a problem with running an SQL script in pandas with `WHERE` in clause which is picking members of a list or tuple

```
    tuple=(1,2,3,4,5,6, 7) # there are 2228 members
    date=20200101

    sql=pd.read_sql_query("""SELECT *                             
                             FROM [MY_TABLE] with (nolock)
                             WHERE [cod] IN (?)
                             and bi_partition>=?""", conn, params=[tuple, date])
```

The error returned:

```
('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The data types varchar and ntext are incompatible in the equal to operator. (402) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')
```

When using params =[str(tuple), str(date)] the error is:

```
 ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The data types varchar and ntext are incompatible in the equal to operator. (402) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')
```

I have tried to fix it with different solutions I found on StackOverflow but it doesn't work.

Anybody can help?

Thank you

Comment: can you try with `params=[str(tuple), str(date)]`?

Comment: @Aviv Yaniv, I have tried but different error returned: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The data types varchar and ntext are incompatible in the equal to operator. (402) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)')

Comment: @Vero set the error you commented on. You can edit your post too :)

Comment: `where [cod] in ?` instead of `(?)` would perhaps fix it.

Comment: unfortunately, no . It gives the same error

Comment: Is `bi_partition` ntext? You can try including the parameters directly in the string and checking if the error still occurs.

Comment: You should avoid using thousands of values with [`IN` clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21178390/1422451) as performance deteriorates. How did you retrieve 2,228 members? From a different query?

Comment: @Parfait yes, but I importem them to pandas as a list

Answer (score 1):

Consider avoiding the use of thousands of separate values in `IN` clause from a Python tuple. Since values derived from a different query, use a subquery from source of values with `IN`.

```
date = "2020-01-01"

sql = """SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, ...
         FROM [MY_TABLE]
         WHERE bi_partition >= ?
           AND [cod] IN 
               (SELECT [cod] FROM myOtherTable)"""

df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, conn, params=[date])
```

Also, consider explicitly identifying columns in `SELECT` for code readability and maintainability where you and readers of your code can see what fields are actually being retrieved and avoid pulling in huge columns like BLOBs or meta identifiers like GUIDs that are not needed for Pandas analytics. See [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/1422451)

Comment: @ Parfait, thank you for the solution! I haven't tried it yet. I understood the idea. It makes sense!