# linq-to-entity List/Array .Contains compiles a query using "WHERE (... OR ...)" instead of "WHERE ... IN (...)"

Tags: c#, .net, linq, db2, linq-to-entities

EntityFramework v6.0

IBM.Data.DB2.EntityFramework v10.5

.NET Framework v4 / C# v4.0 (yes, working on upgrading)

Example:

```
List<long> myIds = new List<long>{ 12345, 23456, 34567 };

IQueryable<myModel> myCollection = (from a in context.TBL_ONE
                                    join b in context.TBL_TWO on a.ENTY equals b.ENTY
                                    select new myModel()
                                    {
                                         LINE_ID = a.LINE_ID
                                    }).AsQueryable();

var results = myCollection.Where(x => myIds.Contains(x.LINE_ID)).ToList(); // here is the issue...
```

The "myCollection" will be very large, and so will the "myIds" collection.

So would prefer it to compile to

```
    SELECT ... WHERE LINE_ID IN (12345, 23456, 34567);
```

however, it compiles to

```
    SELECT ... WHERE LINE_ID = 12345 OR LINE_ID = 23456 OR LINE_ID = 34567;
```

I have tried HashSet, List, and Array - as well as large or small, they all give the same compiled style. Is this due to outdated linq or .net version?

Please let me know if I can provide more information or formatting, I am still a beginner. Thank you

Comment: Does DB2 support Table Valued Parameters or temp tables?

Comment: Add Where like this : from a in context.TBL_ONE.Where(x => IDs.Contains(x.LINE_ID))  You can make a variable : int[] IDs = {12345, 23456, 34567);

Comment: Have you tried feeding a larger collection? Perhaps there are optimizations? Also `in` clause has its own limitations, for SQL servers around 2100.

Comment: @Charlieface i believe so, in stored procedures I can create "global temporary tables" to access during a session...

Comment: @jdweng will try this and let you know

Comment: Sounds like you should upload the list into such a table and join it. That will almost certainly be the fastest.

Comment: @Neistow yes, currently my goal is to use a "filter list" of ~50k-100k id's and I did try 50k as a quick test. unfortunately it came up with a very ugly massive WHERE OR for all the ids. EDIT: i just saw you say that the limit is 2100... oops, that would prevent this strategy for me.

Comment: @Charlieface that would definitely be how I'd do it on stored procedures... i honestly didn't think that'd be possible through Linq. Will try this too, thanks!

Comment: @WayneW if your goal is 50-100k then `where in` clause won't help you. Your database will just return error.

Comment: @WayneW my suggestion is to leverage temp tables. Insert IDs into a temp table and then do a join with the table you want to query. `SqlBulkCopy` is a good way to populate your temp table

Comment: i'm thinking that this might be the best answer that I'm going to get, would you please submit an answer so I can accept? @Neistow

Comment: `SqlBulkCopy` only works on SQL Server not DB2. One solution I've seen is to have a table which stores these IDs, and you insert along with a fixed `BatchID` then join based on that `BatchID`, afterwards you delete those rows. If you find a fast insert method it should be quick.

Comment: @Charlieface you are correct on the first part, I did find DB2BulkCopy but currently trying to figure out a way to map the datatable to entities and perform the join on the server side to avoid loading in all the entities (50k-100k records as mentioned). Your suggestion wouldn't work I don't think because the table I'm filtering on can be over 3 million records and i'd like to do all filtering on db2-side

Comment: Like I said, yo can bulk load into a permanent table and join on that server-side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `in` clause has [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178390/in-clause-limitation-in-sql-server), so you won't be able to stuff 50k into it, you'll just get an error.

You can solve your problem using temp tables in the following way:

1. Create a temp table
2. Bulk/Batch insert your IDs into a temp table
3. Join your temp table with primary

For inserting data into your table you can use [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy), if you're using SQL Server or find any other bulk copy solutions for your DB engine.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer since it eventually led to my resolution, but for future people who might come here... I ended up having to use DB2BulkCopy and resorted to using sqlcommand and a manual connection instead of Linq-to-entities/context so that I can hold onto the connection until I was ready to lose the temp table... and the time savings were definitely worth leaving linq temporarily.