# MySQL / MariaDB - Too many WITH elements in WITH clause

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We are using MariaDB 10.5.13 but the same issue occurs on native MySQL 8.

Getting this error

> 4003 - Too many WITH elements in WITH clause

We have a web application which allows users to search a database containing approx 290,000 substances. A feature of the application is that substances can appear on different chemical inventories and the user can find substances by inventory. The inventories themselves are referred to as `filters` in the database.

There are 3 tables holding the relevant data:

- `substances`: the list of 290,000 substances. Each has a unique `id`.
- `filters`: the list of different chemical inventories. Approx 2300 rows. Each has a unique `id`.
- `filters_substances`: A table which maps `substances` and `filters` together. The relationship is such that any individual substance may appear on >=1 `filters` (i.e. any given substance can be on 1 or more chemical inventories). Approx 1,662,873 rows. The foreign keys used are `filter_id` and `substance_id` to refer to filters and substances respectively.

When the user applies filters there are 2 possible operations alongside each filter.

1. **Find** the substances that are on a given inventory.
2. **Exclude** any substances that are on that inventory.

Find and Exclude can be used in combination. For example the user could do:

- Find substances on `filters` 2 and 300
- Exclude any substances on `filters` 5

The result would be substances that are on inventories 2 and 300, but with any substances on 5 removed from the results.

---

**Edit:**  regarding the previous sentence somebody commented

> you say The result would be substances that are on inventories 2 *and* 300 but your generated sql seems to be saying 2 *OR* 300. Can you clarify which you mean?

The application actually lets the user pick this AND/OR logic too. In this case I did mean "2 or 300" but the user can also toggle this to be "2 and 300". The use-case of this is that they can find:

- All substances which are common to the inventories 2 and 300 (logical AND).
- Any substances which are on 2 or 300 (logical OR) irrespective of whether the substances are listed on both. An OR condition generally results in significantly more substances being returned since the dataset is expanded.

The `filters` are organised into parent `groups` much like a category/sub-category hierarchy (`groups` are the parent category and `filters` belong to `groups`).

---

Or they can just use Find on its own, e.g.

- Find substances on `filters` 2 and 300

There is no use-case for Exclude on its own.

When the user applies filter conditions we write the substances found, `substances.id`, to a table. Every user has their own table to store results which is suffixed with their user ID, e.g. "filtering_1745" is the table for user ID 1745.

#### The problem

This has worked without issue but we recently found when >60 filters were applied we got this error

> Too many WITH elements in WITH clause

The SQL which was generated by the application looks like this. For brevity I've removed some of it but added comments to indicate what the removed portions would be:

```
create table if not exists filtering_1745 
as with 
    fs196 as (select substance_id from filters_substances where filter_id = 196), 
    fs197 as (select substance_id from filters_substances where filter_id = 197), 
    fs198 as (select substance_id from filters_substances where filter_id = 198),
    -- Same as above for ~60 other filters 

    select distinct substance_id as `id` from 
    (
        (
        select substance_id from fs196 
        union 
        select substance_id from fs197 
        union 
        select substance_id from fs198 
        -- Same as above for ~60 other filters
        )
    ) 
sq;
```

In this case all conditions in the query are "Find" (it doesn't use any "Exclude" conditions). If we were also using Exclude conditions then the only difference is that an `EXCEPT` statement is appended to the query. For instance this would exclude filters 170, 178, 180.

```
 except 
 (
     select substance_id from fs170 
     union select substance_id from fs178 
     union select substance_id from fs180 
 ) sq;
```

The same error message appears in this scenario. In other words it's the number of filters being used as opposed to whether they are Find or Exclude as such.

I'm looking for advice on how this could potentially be rewritten.

One thing I considered is along the lines of this.

- Running ~60 separate `SELECT` statements to get the appropriate substance IDs for the "Find" `filters`.
- (Optional) **if** "Exclude" is being used `DELETE` any substances that are `NOT IN` the `filters` that are being excluded.
- `DELETE` any non-unique substance IDs in `filtering_1745`. This is to make sure when the results are presented to a user later it only includes unique substances. If for example a given substance appeared on 5 `filters` it should only be presented once because it's a unique substance.

Any advice would be welcomed.

I looked at some other posts such as ["IN" clause limitation in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21178390/in-clause-limitation-in-sql-server) and [How to put more than 1000 values into an Oracle IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400255/how-to-put-more-than-1000-values-into-an-oracle-in-clause) but I believe these are different problems. I couldn't find anything equivalent to this but if there is something please comment with a link and I'll take a look.

Comment: I guess it should be a limit on the usage of subquery. Why don't you save those `filter_id` in a temporary table and then join ?

Comment: Not sure I understand this - you can't search for a specific substance if you know it?

Comment: you say "The result would be substances that are on inventories 2 and 300" but your generated sql seems to be saying 2 *OR* 300.  Can you clarify which you mean?

Comment: @ysth I've added a clarification. The application actually lets the user select whether to use an AND/OR condition as well.

Comment: This is an example of why it is a bad schema design to have lots of "identical" tables (a la `fs178`) instead of one table with an extra column to distinguish them.

Answer (score 2):

> When the user applies filters there are 2 possible operations alongside each filter.
>
> - Find the substances that are on a given inventory.
> - Exclude any substances that are on that inventory.

Pattern:

```
SELECT substance_id
FROM filters_substances
GROUP BY substance_id
HAVING MAX(filter_id = @filter1)   -- include
   AND MAX(filter_id = @filter1)   -- include
   AND NOT MAX(filter_id = @filter3)  -- exclude
   AND NOT MAX(filter_id = @filter4)  -- exclude
-- ...
```

Then join substances table and receive their details.

If mentioned filter is present in current row then according `filter_id = @filterN` produces 1, if not then it produces 0.

MAX() returns 1 if filter is present in at least one of the rows for the substance (see GROUP BY), and returns 0 if none row for this substance contains this filter.

NOT inverts the output of MAX().

So the substance will be returned only when all filters which should be present returns 1 and all filters which should not be present returns 0 accordingly.

This query may be used either as CTE, or the substances table may be added into FROM with according output list and GROUP BY expressions expanding.

Comment: The question in some places seems to indicate they want an intersection of FIND operations and in some places a union of FIND operations.  This answer implements the former; for the latter, it would be changed to `(MAX() OR MAX() OR MAX()) AND NOT MAX() AND NOT MAX()`

Comment: @ysth Yes, this pattern allows to build complex conditions set using separate conditions combined with AND, OR and parenthesis. Separate conditions can be complex too - for example, "Find substances which matches at least 2 filters from the list {1,3,5,7,9}" is `SUM(filter_id IN (1,3,5,7,9))>=2`.

Comment: SELECT @@group_concat_max_len; to determine maximum length available.  The query is likely exceeding this length limit.

Comment: There are ways of getting different limits.  Someone may show you how.

Comment: @WilsonHauck did you mean to comment to something else?  There's no group concat here.

Comment: When a dynamically created query has thousands of potential options and selection criteria, very large queries (in size of generated query) has the potential to exceed this internal limit of the MySQL instance.  From a MySQL Command Prompt, SELECT @@group_concat_max_len; to determine maximum length available to be used when presented to the MySQL instance.  This may be adjusted in the session with SET @group_concat_max_len=4000000; for limit of 4 million max length to receive an unusually large request and not have a global impact on RAM requirements.

Comment: @WilsonHauck *When a dynamically created query has thousands of potential options and selection criteria, very large queries (in size of generated query) has the potential to exceed this internal limit of the MySQL instance.* See `@@max_allowed_packet`.

Comment: @Akina max_allowed_packet is another whole topic with a hard limit of 1G.

Answer (score 1):

I would offer a suggestion to have a temporary table that may be specific to each user that you can insert all the filters or exclusions and join against that.  This way, you are not limited to 60 or even 1000 entries.  Now, not knowing the language you are using to query the database, you can resolve that.  But lets start with a temp table per user just as example with applicable index per ID.

```
Create Table TempFilters_1745
( filter_id integer )

Create Table TempSubstances_1745
( substance_id integer )
```

Then, instead of building a loop for all the filters or substances, just insert

```
insert into TempFilter_1745 ( filter_id )
   values ( 196 ), ( 197 ), (198 )  ....as many as needed
```

If exclusions

```
insert into TempSubstances_1745 ( substance_id )
   values ( 42 ), ( 57 ) ....as many as needed
```

Then query based on these two temp tables

```
create table if not exists filtering_1745 as
select distinct
      fs.substance_id
   from
      filters_substances fs
         JOIN TempFilter_1745 tmp
            on fs.filter_id = tmp.filter_id
   where
      fs.substance_id 
         NOT IN ( select substance_id
                     from TempSubstances_1745 )
```

Now, if you have no "EXCEPTION" substances to be excluded, that temp table would have no records in it and thus return everything.  But if there WERE records, they would be excluded.  The query itself doesn't change.  You just populate the temp filters or temp substances.

Now, you could take this a slightly different step further instead of multiple temp tables, you could expand and include the user's ID as a secondary column (and include that ID with your inserts and index as well)

```
Create Table TempFilters
( user_id integer, filter_id integer )

Create Table TempSubstances
( user_id integer, substance_id integer )


insert into TempFilter ( user_id, filter_id )
   values ( 1745, 196 ), ( 1745, 197 ), (1745, 198 )  
      ....as many as needed

insert into TempSubstances ( user_id, substance_id )
   values ( 1745, 42 ), ( 1745, 57 ) 
       ....as many as needed

create table if not exists filtering_1745 as
select distinct
      fs.substance_id
   from
      filters_substances fs
         JOIN TempFilter tmp
            on tmp.user_id = 1745 
           AND fs.filter_id = tmp.filter_id
   where
      fs.substance_id 
         NOT IN ( select ts.substance_id
                     from TempSubstances ts
                     where ts.user_id = 1745 )
```

At least this can open your mind to another possible solution.

You can even take the second option a step further by having some additional table allowing a user to save filter sets such as "My XYZ Filter set", that has an auto-increment ID.  Add that ID to the filter/substance tables and include that as part of the inserts.  Then, when a user wants to adjust, they dont have to re-pick the same set of possible 100's of values again, miss something and do again.  I have no idea of your user interface, just a thought.   If not doing based on some "criteria set" ID, make sure you pre-delete the already populated list for each user before starting a new query.

-- Clarification --

You appear to be building dynamically a SQL with what could be 100's or even 1000's of filters (and optionally substances).  Instead of doing that, I am suggesting creating two secondary tables.  One for filters, the other for substances.  Since multiple people can be running queries against their own set, I suggest adding a column for which user the given filter is for as well, hence the create table `TempFilters` and `TempSubstances` and then inserting into this temp table with the user ID, and the filters they are interested in.

Now its just a simple join to that table for that specific user's filters of interest via the create table if not exists...  I was adding the user_id as a filter as to prevent getting filters that someone else may have inserted into this filters table.

```
select distinct
      fs.substance_id
   from
      filters_substances fs
         JOIN TempFilter tmp
            on tmp.user_id = 1745 
           AND fs.filter_id = tmp.filter_id
```

This whole where works regardless of having 2 filters or 2,000 filters.  That is the purpose of a JOIN.  Join the first table (filters_substances) to the second table (TempFilter) based only on the requested user_id (1745) AND The filter ID within filter_substances is also found in the TempFilter table for that user.

So, from that, now I have a list of distinct substances which takes you to the second half of your condition and also the second temp table of substances you do NOT want in the results.  Same way, insert the user ID and substances you want to EXCLUDE in the TempSubstances table.

That is how the WHERE clause comes into play.  The above gives you a list of distinct substances that match the given filters.  Now the WHERE clause is saying... yes, but now, I do NOT want the substance if it is within the second temp table via the NOT IN.

where
fs.substance_id
NOT IN ( select ts.substance_id
from TempSubstances ts
where ts.user_id = 1745 )

You can always separate the pieces to see what they have and how they work.  Create the two temp tables.  Insert a few records into each for some filters and exclusion substances that make sense to a sample you would run.  Make sure to put in some substances you know WOULD exist based on a filter just to confirm seeing it excluded from the final set.

Now, just run a query on the temp filters

```
select * from TempFilters where user_id = 1745
select * from TempSubstances where user_id = 1745
```

and you will see the finite list as entered.  That should make perfect sense.

Now, to the SELECT DISTINCT joining to the temp filters and see what substances come through.  Then do the final that includes the WHERE clause and you'll see the substances no longer in the list.

If you still need assistance, we may need to take this off to a private chat.

Comment: I didn't understand this approach. In `TempFilters_` you seem to be storing the `filters` applied, which make sense. But in `TempSubstances_` you're somehow storing all of the (possibly around 290,000) substance IDs which are *not* part of the results? How are you determining which substances are *not* in the results?

Answer (score 0):

Restructure the schema so that all the `fs178`-like tables are combined into a single table.  `IN` can handle a virtually unlimited number of values.  Or fill a single lookup table and `JOINing` to that.

> Find and Exclude can be used in combination. For example the user
> could do:
>
> Find substances on filters 2 and 300 Exclude any substances on filters
> 5

```
  SELECT ...
      FROM ( 
          SELECT ...
              WHERE filter_id IN (2, 300)
              GROUP BY ...
              HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT filter_id) = 2
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ...
                          WHERE filter_id = 5)
```

That is, with a single table,

- `OR` is implemented as a simple `IN`.
- `AND`: `IN` plus `HAVING COUNT` to make sure all are represented.
- "exclude: `NOT EXISTS`; probably after taking care of the `HAVING COUNT`.

Comment: The application did originally work along these lines. At least in the sense that all of the `substances.id` were put into a single table. When we added the ability to toggle AND/OR logic (see edit in the question) that approach didn't work.