# Shortening if Expressions

Tags: c#

i would like to ask if there a method making this condition shorter like in MSSQL because i have similar coditions also like this.

```
if(docType == "PO" || docType == "II" || docType == "IA" || docType == "IT"  || docType == "OV" || docType == "ID")
{

}
```

in MSSQL

```
SELECT * FROM Documents WHERE docType IN ("PO","II","IA","IT","OV")
```

Comment: Try `contains`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257360/linq-select-objects-in-list-where-exists-in-a-b-c

Comment: I suggested a mix of different answers that should suit you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could construct an array in C#, too:

```
if (new [] {"PO", "II", "IA", "IT", "IV"}.Contains(docType)) {
}
```

You could also use regex:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(docType, "PO|II|IA|IT|IV")) {
}
```

Comment: i find regex to be handy..changing my condition now :D. thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to create a method with the params keyword that handles it for you. This allows you to pass any number of parameters and also the value you are checking

```
private bool IfContains(string needle, params string[] haystack)
{
    bool match = false;

    foreach(string val in haystack)
    {
        if(val == needle)
        {
            match = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return match;
}
```

This can be called with an number of parameters like

```
if(IfContains("Hello", "Hi", "yo", "Hello"))
{
    //DoStuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well:

```
var ids = new[] { "PO", "II", "IA", "IT", "OV", "ID" }
if (ids.Contains(docType)
{

}
```

You could even make it non case sensitive:

```
var ids = new[] { "PO", "II", "IA", "IT", "OV", "ID" }
if (ids.Contains(docType, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, put them in an array and simply do a contains

```
new[] {"a", "b", "c", "d"}.Contains(value)
```

instead of

`if (value == "a" || value == "b" ...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can check from list which you can use to find any doctype in the list :

```
var list = new List<string>(){"PO","II","IA","IT","OV"};
if(list.Any(x=>x == docType))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers are valid and nice, 
I'm just trying to be original here. I often use the following technique in my code to improve readability and use "real words".

I usually spend "more time" on the naming, could be DocTypeIsValid, but I really like having my bool functions starting with "has" or "is". The point here is just to improve reusability and readability.

```
private bool IsDoctypeValid(string docType){
       return docType == "PO" || docType == "II" || docType == "IT" || docType == "IV";
}
```

Note that you could use the technique found in other answers (the `.Contains()` for example) and put it inside the return method, it works the same :) The idea i'm trying to point out is to extract your `if` in a method, so you can do this later on, everywhere :

```
if (IsDoctypeValid(docType)){

}
```

which is super small and super readable.