# C# Concise way to match a string in a list of strings

Tags: c#, string, list

In SQL I can write:-

```
if (product_type in ('abc','def','ghi')) ...
```

How can I write a similarly concise 'if' statement in C#? I don't want to have to pre-create a named string list variable. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq select objects in list where exists IN (A,B,C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257360/linq-select-objects-in-list-where-exists-in-a-b-c)

Comment: @ArturoMenchaca I don't this it is a direct duplicate because the question is asking how to do it without assigning it to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an anonymous collection inline and perform the same method calls on it as if it were named.

```
var product_type = "abc";
// Array
var result = new [] {"abc", "def", "ghi"}.Contains(product_type); // result == true.
// List
var listResult = new List<string> {"abc", "def", "ghi"}.Contains(product_type);
```

Answer (score 1):

To simplify this you would use this line.

```
if (new[] {"abc", "def", "ghi"}.Contains(product_type)) //...
```

Don't forget to add the declaration

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

...or you can create an extension to have the In for everything

```
public static bool In<T>(this T obj, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer, params T[] list)
        {
            if (comparer == null)
                return list.Contains(obj);
            else
                return list.Contains(obj, comparer);
        }

        public static bool In<T>(this T obj, params T[] list)
        {
            return In(obj, null, list);
        }
```

so you could write something like:

```
if ( product_type.In( "abc", "def", "ghi" ) ) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:-

```
if (new List<string> {"Fred", "Jim", "Harry"}.Contains("Jim"))
```

Comment: Thanks Yvette. I posted my answer before I noticed that anyone had replied.