# Filter an IEnumerable in Linq with an array

Tags: c#, linq

How to add a string array

```
string[] BranchIds = {"1","2","3"}
```

inside the Linq Contains?

some thing like this i'm looking for

```
var a =_abc.GetRoutes(0).Where(n => n.BranchId.Contains(BranchIds[])).ToList();
```

Here the BranchId is a String in the model

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257360/linq-select-objects-in-list-where-exists-in-a-b-c) is a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to check whether branchId of route contains array of ids (that will not compile). You should do the opposite - check whether ids array contains branchId of route:

```
var a =_abc.GetRoutes(0).Where(r => BranchIds.Contains(r.BranchId)).ToList();
```

Comment: How to do this if the BranchId is a comma separated string of id's?

Comment: @Sribin First convert that comma-separated string to a list of numbers.

Comment: @Avner i have tried like this ,but not working.    _(userRepo.GetUserList(id).Where(n => BranchIds.Contains(n.StringBranchId.Replace(" ", "").Split(',').ToString()))_

Comment: @Sribin That's a different question, and should be asked separately. Or better yet, search for "split string into array of ints".

Comment: @Sribin then create list of ids from ids string: `var ids = BranchIds.Split(',').ToList()` and then use `ids.Contains(r.BranchId)`

Answer (score 1):

```
var a =_abc.GetRoutes(0).Where(n => BranchIds.Contains(n.BranchId)).ToList();
```

Switch the order, for every `BranchId` in n check if it contained with in `BranchIds`