# How to do a Linq on a comma separated string

Tags: c#, linq

I have another question which is related to this: [Filter an IEnumerable in Linq with an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42791138/filter-an-ienumerable-in-linq-with-an-array). But after this I got a new requirement like,

having an array   `string[] BranchIds = {"1","2","3"}`

```
var a =_abc.GetRoutes(0)
    .Where(r => BranchIds.Contains(r.StringBranchIds))
    .ToList();
```

What if the `StringBranchIds` in this code is also a comma separated string?

I have tried some thing like:

```
var a =_abc.GetRoutes(0)
    .Where(n => BranchIds.Contains((n.StringBranchIds.Replace(" ", "")
        .Split(',')
        .Select(m => Convert.ToInt32(m))
        .ToArray()).ToString()));
```

but no go.

Here inside `Contains` I'm able to give only strings. Is the Linq works like that?

I'm pretty new to Linq, please gimme a hand!

Comment: what is `GetRoutes`?

Comment: And what is the condition? if all of them is in the `BranchIds` or any?

Comment: @Ofir IEnumerable

Comment: `BranchId in this code is also a comma separated string`  how the `BranchId` will looks like and what would be the value in `r.BranchId`

Comment: Could you, please, provide some *examples*? Lets `abc.GetRoutes(0)` return, say `"3,1"` is it a positive or negative example (`BranchIds = {"1","2","3"}`)? What if `abc.GetRoutes(0)` returns `"2,4"` (*partial* intersection)?

Comment: @Sribin you didn't answer my question. `StringBranchId` contains a comma seperated string. you'd like to see wheter **all** of them are within the `BranchIds` or is it enough to satisy the condition if only one is there?

Comment: @Dmitry-abc.GetRoutes will return all the items like routename,routeid,and along with this the StringBranchIds,which will be a string having BranchId separated with comma

Comment: You seem to be comparing two *sets* here; what does contains mean in that case? "Contains any of"? " contains all of"? "Have the same contents"? Also, the code shown does the split **per test element**, which will have awful awful performance. IMO you should do the " rightmost" splits in advance (the ones that aren't per test element), probably into a `HashSet<T>` or similar

Comment: @Marc Gravell -I'm not sure how the contains works,but I need to filter it out with only the BranchId that is Contained in the StringBranchIds

Comment: @OfirWinegarten All of them

Comment: @Sribin k; let me rephrase; you have miltiple "routes" from `GetRoutes`; you are trying to filter the "routes"; each "route" has multiple branch ids, and you're trying to compare that *against* a fixed multiple branch ids; so: if a route has branch ids {1,2,3} and the fixed branch ids is {2,4} - should that be returned? or not? if "yes", this is not a `Contains` -  it is an "any intersection"; if "no", then we need to know the full rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Contains` method asks whether a **single** value is in a wider sequence/list. You don't *have* that; you have (for each branch):

- a `StringBranchIds` against the "route", which we can *relatively* easily convert to a flat list
- a `BranchIds` that is the fixed list we're testing against

This is **nothing to do with contains**.

Assuming you mean "any intersection", then this would be something like:

```
var a =_abc.GetRoutes(0).Where(n =>
   n.StringBranchIds.Replace(" ", "").Split(',').Any(
        id => BranchIds.Contains(id)
   ));
```

What this does is:

- split the `StringBranchIds` into pieces
- for each of these, test whether it is contained in `BranchIds`

Note, however, that this is *not* optimal in terms of performance - lots of `O(N)` testing. If `BranchIds` is relatively small, you'll probably be fine (any `O(1)` "improvements" will probably be *slower* than the `O(N)`, for small `N`). If `BranchIds` is *long*, you could pre-process it into a `HashSet<string>`, etc.

Note that I haven't parsed anything to `int` - there's no need to, and that won't help your performance.

Additionally, you should think about would be pre-processing the `StringBranchIds` into something amenable to testing; this doesn't necessarily involve many changes. For example, from here:

```
public string StringBranchIds {get;set;}
```

we can change to:

```
private string _stringBranchIds;
public string StringBranchIds {
    get { return _stringBranchIds; }
    set {
        if(value != _stringBranchIds) {
            _stringBranchIds = value;
            _splitIds = null; // only if actually a change
        }
    }
}
private string _splitIds;
internal string[] GetSplitIds() {
    return _splitIds ?? (_splitIds =
        (_stringBranchIds ?? "").Replace(" ", "").Split(','));
}
```

Now we just change our method to use `n.GetSplitIds()` instead of `n.StringBranchIds`, and it will get back the same array of ids until the value is changed. Much cheaper than splitting it each time.

Comment: Although as the name suggests Ids in the form `"1"`, `"2"` etc. should probably be `int`s at least in the `BranchIds` array.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder there's enough overhead here already; there's nothing in the test being performed that requires us to parse it; but yes, if `BranchIds` was an `int[]` (or similar), then in my later edit (press F5) we could change `GetSplitIds` to return `int[]` also, and add the parsing there

Comment: I agree it's not needed with the example that is shown here, however, it seems it probably should be an `int` for, probably correct, usage later on

Comment: In the question, he asked "what if the StringBranchIds in this code is also a comma separated string?". That means he has a list of strings, each being a comma separated string of ints. See my answer which takes that into account, and feel free to merge it with yours.

Comment: @kall2sollies Thanks for your support,but in the  question I only meant -a single string which is having integers that are comma separated.

Comment: @Sribin that's what was not perfectly clear to me, so I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With you split logic

```
var a =_abc.GetRoutes(0).Where(r =>
          !r.StringBranchIds.Replace(" ", "").Split(',').Except(BranchIds).Any()).ToList();
```

This will get back only the routes that have all of their `StringBranchIds` contained within the `BranchIds`.