# How to get a list of records based on an informed enumerated list in a 1 to many relationship - EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to pass an enumerated list and get only the records that have the "Application" field equivalent to the one in the enumerated list, according to the sql described below:

```
select * from "FormaContato" as "fc"
inner join "FormaContatoAplicacao" as "fca" ON "fc"."Id" = "fca"."FormaContatoId"
where "fca"."AplicacaoId" in (2, 1, ...)

public enum AplicacaoEnum
{
    [Description("PESSOA FÍSICA")]
    Nenhum = 1,
    [Description("PESSOA JURÍDICA")]
    ContatoTelefonico = 2
}

public IQueryable<FormaContato> GetAllByAplicacao(List<AplicacaoEnum> aplicacaoList = null)
{
    var data = DbSet.
        Include(x => x.FormaContatoAplicacoes)
        .Where(x=> x.FormaContatoAplicacoes.Aplicacao == aplicacaoList ????????? Here.)
        .AsNoTracking();

    return data;
        
}
```

How to do this?
Thanks! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq select objects in list where exists IN (A,B,C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257360/linq-select-objects-in-list-where-exists-in-a-b-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for the `.Contains()` method.

So in your case it would be something like:

```
var data = DbSet
     .Include(x => x.FormaContatoAplicacoes)
     .Where(x=> aplicacaoList.Contains(x.FormaContatoAplicacoes.Aplicacao))
     .AsNoTracking();
```

Also please notice that if you are not about to use `FormaContatoAplicacoes` later in your flow, I see no reason to use the `.Include()` here.