# How to filter from multiple colums using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core, icollection

How can I search for an item in the string array in a list where these values can be in multiple columns.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] strtosearch = { "abc", "xyz", "123" };

        }
    }
```

I have a string array like above where I want to filter for these values from the below model.

```
    public class Source
    {
        public string S1 { get; set; }
        public ICollection<InnerSource> InnerSources { get; set; }
    }

    public class InnerSource
    {
        public string D1 { get; set; }
        public ICollection<InnerSource2> InnerSource2s  { get; set; }
    }
    public class InnerSource2
    {
        public string **D1ToSearch** { get; set; }
        public string D2 { get; set; }
        public string **D3ToSearch** { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here in the first four with values D1ToSearch  or D3ToSearch has the value abc and xyz . so my query result should limit to the first three entries.

```
var example = new List<Source>
            {
                new Source
                {
                    S1 ="1",
                    InnerSources = new List<InnerSource>
                    {
                        new InnerSource
                        {
                            D1 ="2",
                            InnerSource2s= new List<InnerSource2>
                            {
                                new InnerSource2
                                {
                                    D1ToSearch ="abc",
                                    D2="3",
                                    D3ToSearch="222"
                                },new InnerSource2
                                {
                                    D1ToSearch ="122",
                                    D2="3",
                                    D3ToSearch="abc"
                                }
                                ,new InnerSource2
                                {
                                    D1ToSearch ="abc",
                                    D2="3",
                                    D3ToSearch="333"
                                }
```

Here in the first four with values D1ToSearch  or D3ToSearch has the value abc and xyz . so my query result should limit to the first three entries.

```
                                ,new InnerSource2
                                {
                                    D1ToSearch ="opq",
                                    D2="3",
                                    D3ToSearch="xyz"
                                },
                                ,new InnerSource2
                                {
                                    D1ToSearch ="arstbc",
                                    D2="3",
                                    D3ToSearch="uvw"
                                } } } } } };
```

If D1ToSearch **or** D3ToSearch contains any of the above values I would like to return that row.Above is  a sample list added as an expamle .

How can I do this using LINQ query?

Comment: I do not understand how to filter from Model. Filter we can apply to query. Show your query or specify root entity.

Comment: Have you tried it with LINQ or without LINQ?

Comment: This seems to apply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31639011/4892466

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Answer (score 0):

With nested lists, you can use `SelectMany` to collapse these and get to just the inner objects. Then you can do your OR comparison on the two fields you indicated, like so:

```
example
    .SelectMany(e => e.InnerSources.SelectMany(i2 => i2.InnerSource2s))     
    .Where(e => strtosearch.Contains(e.D1ToSearch) || strtosearch.Contains(e.D3ToSearch));
```